# another Python indentation issue

Tags: python, python-3.3

for reason, now my code has some weird formatting issue.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        import doctest

   # @@@ UNCOMMENT THESE ONE AT A TIME TO GET THE TESTS TO PASS.
   # @@@ WHEN YOU ARE FINISHED, LEAVE ONLY THE "allTests.txt" line uncommented.

 #  doctest.testfile("noConsecDupsTests.txt", verbose=True)
  # doctest.testfile("isVowelTests.txt", verbose=True)
  # doctest.testfile("countVowelsTests.txt", verbose=True)
 #  doctest.testfile("allVowelsATests.txt", verbose=True)
 #  doctest.testfile("syllableHelperTests.txt", verbose=True)
#   doctest.testfile("removeSilentETests.txt", verbose=True)
 #  doctest.testfile("removeEdWhenNotASyllableTests.txt", verbose=True)
  #  doctest.testfile("countSyllablesTests.txt", verbose=True)
        doctest.testfile("allTests.txt", verbose=True)
```

Python 3.3.2 is saying that the indentation error is in the first line of the code... I'm really confused. I've never been so stumped on such a simple topic.

Comment: It looks like the initial "if" is indented, which it shouldn't be

Comment: It is not in my code; for some reason stackOverFlow wouldn't allow me to post it otherwise.

Comment: Paste in the full error message and traceback too.  It will help.  We can't *see* what you see unless you show us what you see.

Comment: "SyntaxError: expected an indent block". It comes up as a pop up. There is red highlighting that follows after the colon on the first line.

Comment: Is it the full source code?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you are trying to run this in the Python REPL? As opposed to saving it to a file and then running it?

Python REPL ends a code block after an empty line. Try saving this in a file, say `test.py` and then call it from command line using `python test.py`.